# Where to check the default impersonation setting in IIS Express?

Tags: iis, iis-express

On my computer when I start the IIS Express and navigate to localhost:8080, I get this 500.24 Error.
and it suggests that the most likely cause is: `system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true`.

[image]

To get rid of this error I had to add a new web.config file to C:\Users\joeb\Documents\My Web Sites\WebSite1\Web.config, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="false"/>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I have to add this web.config file here to make this error go away.

I tried this on a different computer and it works out of the box with out having this web.config file.

I'm not sure whats causing this problem... Everything I read about IIS Express and impersonation is telling me that the default value for impersonation is set to false.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening here.

Comment: That can come in machine.config and root web.config, both in .NET Framework installation folder, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/understanding-iis-configuration-delegation#configuration-hierarchy-and-effective-configuration You might have modified them without even notice.

Comment: You are correct excatly! I was able to dig in to the root web.config file and it had impersonate set to true in there for some reason... once i turned that off.. its working fine now. Thanks so much!

Comment: is your issue resolved? If your issue is solved then I request you to post the solution and mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Lex Li mentioned in the comments, the problem was in my root web.config file [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config]

It had:

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Once I commented that out .. it worked fine.

Hopefully this will help other people who face the same issue.